# Rotate x-axis of r partykit tree plot

Tags: r, plot, rotation, axis-labels, party

I've built a decision tree using ctree in R and visualize the tree using the ctree model in the party package.

I am very happy with the results and the overall visualization. However, I cannot interpret the 'confusion' in every leaf node, since the x-axis labels either overlap or are missing!

Currently I use the following command:

```
plot(fitCtree, main="Title", gp = gpar(fontsize = 2))
```

I've searched quite a lot to find the (simple?) answer... to no avail. 
Can you help me out?

Cheers,
Arend

[image: x axis labels in visualization of R decision tree (ctree) using partykit package overlap and ideally should be perpendicual to the x-axis]

Comment: Have you seen this post [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12000533/4752675] It has a complicated solution, but I think that it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

One option that is easily available in `node_barplot()`, the panel function employed here, is to rotate the axis labels rather than rotating the entire plot (as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12000533/4752675 mentioned by @G5W). For example you can set `rot = 45, just = c("right", "top")` to obtain a rotation by 45 degrees with top-right justification of the labels.

Depending on the length of the labels, it might be necessary to increase the lower margin of the plot to allow for enough space. One can do this either with pushing a separate viewport - or via the convenience argument `margins` that I just added to the development version of `partykit` on R-Forge.

As an illustration:

```
install.packages("partykit", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
library("partykit")
ct <- ctree(Species ~ ., data = iris)
plot(ct, margins = c(3, 0, 0, 0),
  tp_args = list(rot = 45, just = c("right", "top")))
```

[image: ctree with rotated labels]